# Implementing Instagram-like time formatting with Joda-Time

Tags: java, jodatime

If there isn't an easy way currently, I'll just build out the functionality, but I'm new to Joda-Time and was wondering if there is a simple way to do this:

Basically, you have a `time` in ISO8601 format, and you create a `new DateTime(time);` using Joda-Time.

Now, if the time was 5 seconds ago, I'd like it to read "5s", if it was 10 minutes ago, "10m", 17 hours ago, "17h", 3 weeks ago, "3w".

Clearly, if something was written 79 seconds ago, it realizes that this is more than 1 minute, and instead opts to check this in minutes, and instead says "1m" instead of "79s".

**Update:**

So far, my quick solution is this:

```
public void setTimestamp() {
        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
        if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusSeconds(1)) == 1) {
           timestamp = "1s";
        } else if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusMinutes(1)) == 1) {
            timestamp = Seconds.secondsBetween(timeCreated, now).getSeconds() + "s";
        } else if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusHours(1)) == 1) {
            timestamp = Minutes.minutesBetween(timeCreated, now).getMinutes() + "m";
        } else if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusDays(1)) == 1) {
            timestamp = Hours.hoursBetween(timeCreated, now).getHours() + "h";
        } else if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusWeeks(1)) == 1) {
            timestamp = Days.daysBetween(timeCreated, now).getDays() + "d";
        } else if (DateTimeComparator.getInstance().compare(timeCreated, now.minusYears(1)) == 1) {
            timestamp = Weeks.weeksBetween(timeCreated, now).getWeeks() + "w";
        } else {
            timestamp = Years.yearsBetween(timeCreated, now).getYears() + "y";
        }
}
```

It still requires some testing, but from first looks, it seems to work.

Comment: I'm using Java. momentjs wouldn't serve me.